# AngularJS - Adding a variable value back into controller $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have a date that is being being returned in the format:

```
2016-07-25 10:50:14
```

I've created a variable that gets the data and strips out the dashes, spaces and colons with:

```
var newDate = $scope.details["Created At"].replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
```

Now the with console.log(date); the date is being returned as:

```
20160725105014
```

I guess my main question is how can I take that variable data and add it back into the controller $scope so that I can call it into my html and use angular date formatting such as:

```
{{ details.newDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma' }}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like

```
$scope.details.newDate = $scope.details["Created At"].replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '')
```

Comment: Yep that worked. With {{ details.newDate }} it shows "20160725105014" . but know I have just created a new issue when I use " {{ details.newDate | date:"MM-dd-yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss" }} " it returns "null". So I will start a new question for that issue. Thanks for  the help and the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your desired value in a variable "newDate" you can then assign that same variable to some other $scope variable to be used in your view.

```
var newDate = $scope.details["Created At"].replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
$scope.myStrippedDate = newDate;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".